# ST_DWithin Optimization Postgis

Tags: postgis, performance, optimization, st-dwithin

I've got two datasets - 1) a set of buildings in LA and 2) fiber optic cable maps from a company called Zayo which covers the whole of the US.  I'd like to find the buildings within a certain distance to the fiber. The SRID is 4326 and it's stored as a geometry, not geography (as far as I can tell).

Here's my code:

```
select *
from la_records
inner join zayo_fiber
on ST_DWithin(zayo_fiber."geom", la_records."geom", .001);
```

The code looks to work, but  it takes forever - 10 minutes. Here's the Explain:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.21..43.81 rows=1 width=3167517)
->  Seq Scan on zayo_fiber  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=5 width=3167299)
->  Index Scan using sidx_la_records_geom on la_records  (cost=0.21..8.54 rows=1 width=218)
    Index Cond: (geom && st_expand(zayo_fiber.geom, '0.001'::double precision))
    Filter: ((zayo_fiber.geom && st_expand(geom, '0.001'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(zayo_fiber.geom, geom, '0.001'::double precision))
Time: 0.045s
```

To speed up this query, should I break up the zayo fiber into smaller subsegments, then index it?

Comment: how far is .001?

Comment: some of this info might help with optimizing:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/194576/72697

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: PolyGeo - Edited the  question - thanks for pointing that out to me

Answer (score 1):

So the very long multi-line-segment from zayo_fiber was causing the efficiency issue. I ended up using ST_Dump to break it up into 55,000 rows, which I then indexed. The query now runs in less than a second.