# Fast way to convert Polygons to Points in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometry, geometry-conversion, optimization

What's the fastest way to convert a polygon to a point in PostGIS?

I don't care *where* the point is in relation to the geometry, but the resulting point does need to be consistent.

Using `ST_Centroid` takes about 19 seconds to do it for 1000 polygons, which seems very slow (I need to do it repeatedly for millions!), but that's probably because it's calculating the centroid of the feature.

I briefly flirted with `ST_DumpPoints`, but that seems to take even longer (over 30 seconds for the same 1000) points.

So what's the fastest way to do this?

Comment: You probably already did this but make sure you have indexes/vacuum/analyze/server performance... http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/194576/72697

Comment: Time taken using ST_centroid will greatly depend on the complexity of the polygons. Perhaps some method using the centroid of an mbr might be faster. I am slightly puzzled at using ST_DumpPoints: this will create multiple points per polygon, whereas I am assuming you just want one? If your polygons complex then this would explain why ST_DumpPoints took a long time.

Comment: Would your polygons be conducive to centroids of bounding boxes? Perhaps you could pull them from the indexing?

Comment: Indexes are irrelevant here.  These must be massive polygons...`ST_Centroid` cpu time is dominated by deserialization in my experience.

Comment: Try the `ST_XMin` and `ST_XMax` functions and use the mid-points.

Comment: It's unclear if you want the fastest way to **generate** points or the fastest way to **access** points.  There is never a need to ever do something expensive "repeatedly." Instead, alter your database design to include the data you need.

Comment: When you say you don't care where, you mean the point has to intersect the polygon, but it doesn't matter whether on edge or interior? If so, you could simply just take the first point, ST_PointN, which I think would be very fast as no calculations are necessary.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan warning! you have to check if you need real centroïd or false centroïd. It depends if you have hole  or L polygon shape and if you need you point in object of origin entities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The spped of the different approaches will, of course, depend on the complexity of the polygons involved. The [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) to calculate a centroid, as with **ST_Centroid**, require you to actually deserialize the polygon as @dbaston has said, and also do the calculation using all the points. **ST_Xmax**, **ST_Xmin** and **ST_Ymax**, **ST_Ymin** will be faster, as there is less computation involved than with the centroid. Perhaps, surprisingly, adding a spatial index does not appear to increase the speed of these min/max functions, even though the bounding box is an integral part of Gist (spatial) indexing -- which, as dbaston has pointed out in the comments, is because the bbox points are stored as single precision and, are therefore, unusable by the bounding box functionns.  [ST_PointOnSurface](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointOnSurface.html) is guaranteed to find a point in the polygon, but as with ST_Centroid, involves an algorithm actually using all the points, also see this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76498/how-is-st-pointonsurface-calculated).

ST_DumpPoints seems wasteful, as it returns an array of all points, so you have all the expense of deserializing the geometry into a point array, and you are then throwing away n-1 of the points.

The ***fastest*** method I could find was using [ST_PointN](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_PointN.html) in conjunction with [ST_Exteriorring](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html), as ST_PointN requires a Linestring, which ST_ExteriorRing returns. ST_PointN only needs to extract the first point (in the example below), and doesn't need to do any other calculations.

Here are some fairly arbitrary numbers for some tests using a table of 10,000 geometries each with at least 1000 points, repeating 10 times, and averaging, on my laptop, in descending speed order:

```
SELECT ST_PointOnSurface(geom) FROM sometable;
```

took 2345 ms.

```
SELECT ST_Centroid(geom) FROM sometable;
```

took 460 ms.

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint(ST_Xmin(geom), ST_Ymin(geom)) FROM sometable;
```

took 259 ms.

```
SELECT ST_PointN(ST_Exteriorring(geom), 1) FROM sometable;
```

took 112ms.

I did the same tests with smaller geometries and the gap between the **ST_PointN** and **ST_XMax/ST_Ymax (or min equivalents)** was closer, but ST_PointN was still the clear winner.

You have stated that you don't care where the point is, but that it needs to be consistent, so **PointN(geom, 1)** would appear to meet your purposes, as it will always return the first point and is the fastest.

Comment: I'm glad this works for you. I was concerned I was answering the wrong question. You must have some very, very large polgons or a very, very slow computer for some of the numbers you were reporting above. I am guessing this approach is saving a lot of time.

Comment: Bounding boxes are stored as single-precision, which is why they aren't used for `ST_XMin` etc.

Comment: @dbaston, thanks. I really need to learn to grok the source better.